# Team Project Settings menu item missing for Project Administrator

Tags: azure-devops

I am a part of the project administrators group in VSTS so I should have the ability to edit project level information (i.e. create Iterations), however, when I click the gear icon, the Project Settings option is missing.  Instead there is an option "Default Team Settings" which, when selected, navigates to the overview of the members of the team.  From this page, the gear icon does have the Project Settings option, but selecting it just launches the project profile.  I need to access the Project Settings from the Work tab (as far as I understand from the Microsoft VSTS documenation) in order to add Areas and Iterations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a team context (`https://xxx.visualstudio.com/[team project]/[team]`), then the admin page is in team context, so there is **Project Setting**, so you just move mouse to **setting icon** and choose **Work** to manage current team’s Iterations or Areas.

Otherwise (`https://xxx.visualstudio.com/[team project]`), then the admin page is in project context, so there is **Default Team Settings**, you can move mouse to **setting icon** and choose **Work** to add Areas or Iterations.

Regarding your scenario, when you select Default Team Settings option, it will redirect to admin page of team context, so there is Project Setting option.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I feel like a complete idiot - that shouldn't have been too difficult to figure out!